# python convert single digit day and month to two digits

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to read and convert the following datetime `"6/5/2014 00:09:32"` to `"Mon Mar 09 07:07:18 +0000 2015"`.

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime('6/5/2014 00:09:32', '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
```

Gives me a traceback with:

```
ValueError: time data '6/5/2014 00:00:07' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'
```

I tried using %e for single digit days as suggested here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatting-Calendar-Time.html#index-strftime-2660, but datetime just says it doesn't recognize 'e'.

Unless I am missing something it looks like single digit days and months are my problem, but from the documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) I don't see a way to get python's datetime to read single digit days or months. But this seems silly. What am I missing?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need `'Y'` not `'y'`:

```
In [412]:

d = dt.datetime.strptime('6/5/2014 00:09:32', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
d
Out[412]:
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 6, 0, 9, 32)
```

From the docs `'Y'` corresponds to:

> Year with century as a decimal number.

You tried `'y'` which is:

> Year without century as a decimal number [00,99].

Comment: Ok. I feel lame for looking in the wrong place, but thanks for the correct answer (and fast too!).